# Finding if class method is called externally or internally

Tags: ruby

```
class MyParent
  def self.foo
    if this_method_was_called_internally?
      puts "yay" 
    else
      puts "boo"
    end
  end
end

class MyLibrary < MyParent
  foo # yay
end

MyLibrary.foo # boo
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Inspect the stack -- is there anything tell-tale in there? Otherwise, I think your out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no. You can however play with `caller`, it gives you access to the call stack, much like an exception backtrace:

```
def this_method_was_called_internally?
  caller[1].include?(...)
end
```

(`caller[1]` would be the previous call, i.e. the method calling `this_method...`)

It's very hackish, and the information you get from `caller` may not be enough.

Please don't use this other than to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford a little modification of your code:

```
class MyParent
  def self.foo(scope)
    if scope == self
      puts "yay" 
    else
      puts "boo"
    end
  end
end

class MyLibrary < MyParent
  foo(self) # yay
end

MyLibrary.foo(self) # boo
```